# Spring Integration Message Routing By Type of Part of Payload

Tags: spring-integration

I've this class:

```
public interface ProcessMessage<T extends ProcessData, C, D> {
    T getProcessData();
    C getOperation();
    D getDetail();
}
```

I'm flowing this message between channels. At some point I need to use a router based on the type of `processData` field. 
I've some concrete classes that implement `ProcessData` interface and I need to route `ProcessMessage` instance to some channel.

I've implemented something like below but if there is a better solution I'll be glad to hear.

```
<int:router input-channel="processMilestonePassChannel" expression="payload.processData.class.name">
    <int:mapping value="some.pkg.XProcessData" channel="channelX"/>
    <int:mapping value="some.pkg.YProcessData" channel="channelY"/>
</int:router>
```

Comment: Actually, your router looks good. `PayloadTypeRouter` isn't for you, because you want to determine a type of some part of your payload. SpEL in this case is OK. What issue do you have?

Comment: Hi Artem, thanks. It works but it just doesn't seem good to me. I'm asking this to get some better ideas.

Comment: Don't worry, it's OK. You have only one component - router and don't have any Java code lines - SpEL does the stuff for you! Keep her steady!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, your router looks good. `PayloadTypeRouter` isn't for you, because you want to determine a type of some part of your `payload`. SpEL in this case is OK.

You have only one component - `router`, and don't have any Java code lines - SpEL does the stuff for you! Keep her steady!